# The test succeeds in the editor, but it does not appear on the mobile

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm currently developing a game for Android on Unity 2020 as solo.
I have done most of the game development already, all I have to do is enable ads.

I worked by referring to the official Google Ads documentation and other literature, but it didn't work.
Specifically, what I did was register a new app with Admob and issue a new ad ID. In addition, I am applying to publish the app on the Google Play console.

The code is exactly as it was introduced in the documentation;

```
void Start()
{
    // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
    MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });

    RequestBanner();
}

private void RequestBanner()
{

    string adUnitId = "(correct Unit ID)";

    // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
    BannerView bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);

    // Create an empty ad request.
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

    // Load the banner with the request.
    bannerView.LoadAd(request);

    // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
    //bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Top);
}
```

The test was displayed successfully in the editor, like below;

[image: Image by https://uni.gas.mixh.jp/unity/android-admob.html]

Then I built the game and tried it on my mobile phone.
Then the advertisement will not be displayed.

Is it because the app hasn't been published to Google Play yet?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the ad just started to appear.
Probably because it wasn't long enough since I created the project.